# FlatList is rendering all the items when whenever new item added in a list

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am using firebase for fetching my items and using redux to manage store but but when ever new item fetched from server flatList render all rows again which cause performance issue i am using flatList for showing chat beacause i am creating an chat app

Comment: show the code for the component?

Comment: `switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MESSAGES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {messages: action.myitems});`